# How do I use a Nuget package in the Artifacts page in my Docker Build step?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In my Azure Devops project, under the tab "Artifacts", I have a package `MyPackage`.

[image]

In my build pipeline, I have this step:

```
  - stage: Build
    displayName: "Build"
    jobs:
    - job: 
      steps:
      - task: Docker@2
        inputs:
          containerRegistry: 'TEST container registry'
          repository: 'mycontainerregistry/backend'
          command: 'buildAndPush'
          buildContext: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
          Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
          tags: |
            $(Build.BuildId)
            latest
```

The Dockerfile being built is the standard generated one by Visual Studio:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject.API.csproj", "MyProject.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject.API"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.API.dll"]
```

Now, the problem is with the `dotnet restore` command. This step fails because the restore command can't find the MyPackage nuget from the docker build context. How can I make `dotnet restore` find `MyPackage` when running through `docker build`?

Answer (score 2):

If you have private feed you need to add a source using `dotnet nuget add source`

```
dotnet  nuget sources add -name "SomeName" -source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/YourFeed/nuget/v3/index.json -username anything -password $TOKEN
```

And to pass System.AccessToken you need to use `ARG`

```
FROM alpine

ARG TOKEN
RUN dotnet  nuget sources add -name "SomeName" -source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/YourFeed/nuget/v3/index.json -username anything -password $TOKEN
```

and then in YMAL

```yaml
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'devopsmanual-acr'
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: 'stackoverflow/85-docker/DOCKERFILE'
    arguments: '--build-arg TOKEN=$(System.AccessToken)'
```

Please split you buildAndPush as it doesn't allow passing arguments into two separate task. For more details please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961751/environment-variable-not-injected-into-multi-stage-docker-build-on-azure-devops).

Please also make sure that you can `Build Service` has contributor role on feed settings.

Comment: Thanks for your help. To be sure, if I use the AccessToken method, how do I generate the token?

Comment: `System.AccessToken` is predefined variable, no need to generate it - please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken). And `TOKEN` is an argument in your dockerfile.

Comment: For anyone reading this, the 'new' syntax is: `RUN dotnet nuget add source`

Answer (score 1):

The solution of [Krystof Madey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64984076/1376543) does not work for me. At the end I followed the guide [How to use secrets inside your Docker build using Azure DevOps](https://damienaicheh.github.io/azure/devops/2022/08/15/docker-secrets-azure-devops-en.html) and [Use your Azure DevOps System.AccessToken for Docker builds… safely](https://medium.selbstge.cloud/user-your-azure-devops-system-accesstoken-for-docker-builds-safely-ce6e0702503f) to finish the job successfully.

At the end my result looks like the following:
Job:

```
- job: create_image_and_push_to_acr
  displayName: "Create image and push to ACR"
  variables:
    DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
  steps:
    - script: echo $(System.AccessToken) >> azure_devops_pat
      displayName: Get PAT
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: "Build"
      inputs:
        command: build
        containerRegistry: $(connection_name)
        Dockerfile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile
        repository: "my_repository"
        tags: $(applicationComponentVersion)
        arguments: '--secret id=AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT,src=./azure_devops_pat'
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: "Push"
      inputs:
        command: push
        containerRegistry: $(connection_name)
        repository: "my_repository"
        tags: $(applicationComponentVersion)
```

And inside the docker file:

```
RUN  --mount=type=secret,id=AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT,dst=/azure_devops_pat \
 dotnet nuget add source --username this_value_could_be_anything --password `cat /azure_devops_pat` --store-password-in-clear-text --name my_name "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/.../nuget/v3/index.json" && \
 dotnet restore "src/MyProject.csproj"
```