# How to make Azure App Service for containers "use" .env variables?

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-devops, dotenv

I've deployed a Python web app using Azure App Service from a docker container in Container Registries. In my app I'm using dotenv to load secrets, and locally I running `docker run --env-file=.env my-container` to pass the `.env` variables, but I can't really figure out how to do it when deployed to Azure?

I'm using dotenv in the following way:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

SERVER = os.getenv("SERVER_NAME")
DATABASE = os.getenv("DB_NAME")
USERNAME = os.getenv("USERNAME")
PASSWORD = os.getenv("PASSWORD")
PORT = os.getenv("PORT", default=1433)
DRIVER = os.getenv("DRIVER")
```

How can I have my container fetch the .env variables?

I've added the secrets to Azure Key Vault, but I'm not sure how to pass these to the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of passing variables to Dockerfile check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64968293/2347999)

Please add argument after from

```
FROM alpine

ARG serverName
RUN echo $serverName
```

and then run it like this

```yaml
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'devopsmanual-acr'
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: 'stackoverflow/85-docker/DOCKERFILE'
    arguments: '--build-arg a_version=$(SERVER_NAME)'
```

In terms of fetching values from KeyVault you can use [Azure Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet)

```yaml
# Azure Key Vault
# Download Azure Key Vault secrets
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 
    keyVaultName: 
    secretsFilter: '*'
    runAsPreJob: false # Azure DevOps Services only
```

Be aware that by deault Variables created by this task are marked as secret, so they are not mapped an environment variables.

[You can still try to use your approach but first you need to map it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)

```yaml
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Using an input-macro works: $(mySecret)"
    Write-Host "Using the env var directly does not work: $env:MYSECRET"
    Write-Host "Using a global secret var mapped in the pipeline does not work either: $env:GLOBAL_MYSECRET"
    Write-Host "Using a global non-secret var mapped in the pipeline works: $env:GLOBAL_MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR" 
    Write-Host "Using the mapped env var for this task works and is recommended: $env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret) # the recommended way to map to an env variable
```

Comment: I also found this [method](https://christianhenrikreich.medium.com/python-get-secrets-from-azure-key-vault-with-azure-cli-credentials-fef1968b2efe), but is fetching the secrets directly in the code a bad idea?

Comment: Issue which you may get here is if your secrets would be logged somehow. If not, than you are ready to go. If you use just in the script I mean fetch secrets, pass them and they are safe - you are fine. Just check the logs and try to find them - this is the best idnicator.

Answer (score 2):

To pick up secrets from Key Vault and use them as env vars in your app, use Key Vault references as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Then just add the reference to your App Settings. For example:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)
```

That's it. No need to amend your dotenv code to do anything special, as App Settings are already injected as environment variables by App Service into your application.

Don't forget to add your App Service instance (managed identity) to the Key Vault's access policy, otherwise none of this works -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#granting-your-app-access-to-key-vault

Comment: This is actually quite nice. So if I have 6 secrets, I add 6 App Settings - one for each secret?

Comment: I accepted the first answer since it seemed to work out initially, but I ended up going with your solution.

Comment: I'm not here for the points, i'm here to see the world NOT burn.